# Join AR models without relations() methods in YII

Tags: php, join, yii, many-to-many

Im new to yii and in the php's frameworks world too. Im trying to build a many to many relation and with the relations() methods it works good. I'm wondering if it would be possible to join ar models without using the relations() methods? Should I write a getAnotherARModel method with a simple query in it, which is return with the model? (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I did not want to reinvent anything. My database's structure doesnt allow me to use relations. I should have add more details about my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was not so clear, and i did not explain why I am trying to do this. I can't use the relations methods because of my database structure. There isn't direct connection between my tables (in one of the tables the connection key isn't stored). I solved the problem by writing a simple method which return with the searched ar object. Here is my method:

```
    public function getPubData($key)
    {
        return PubData::model()->findByPk(array('key' => $key));
    }
```

And after that you can reach this object like this:

```
$publicData = $model->getPubData($key);
```

Its the same if you are building a many to many join, the only difference is the query.